# Integrate Google docs editor into my web application

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api, ms-wopi

I have my own cloud storage and own file management system, I am trying to integrate with Microsoft and Google in order to add a document online editor to permit my clients to collaborate and share content.

I have started working with Microsoft using their Cloud Storage Program and using WOPI protocol, and everything is going fine till now.

On the other side, I haven't found a similar one for Google :/, there's something called Google Drive API, but it seems only for documents stored on their cloud.

I have got inspired by what Dropbox is doing for online document editors using both Microsoft and Google.

Does anyone know how it is feasible with Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at Google sheets api , or google docs api.   They will let you programmatically edit files.

- [Google drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api) - File storage api.
- [Google docs api](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/overview) - programmatically edit google docs files.
- [Google sheets api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) - programmatically edit google sheets files.

But there is no wysiwyg editor really for drive.   Unless the user has access to the file, and it resides in drive then they could open it in the google drive web app on their own account.

Comment: But these APIs you are listing don't include a really docs editor UI, just editing by code. If you notice Dropbox behavior, they are showing a UI very similar to that of Google. I was wondering how it is feasible if Google are not providing such tools!

Comment: And moreover, the storage is in Dropbox, nothing is saved in Google storage

Comment: Google is not DropBox.    Again there is no wysiwyg editor for drive.   They simply do not have the tool you are looking for.    No one can tell you why Google has is not offering this tool.  My guess its because they want you to use the google drive web app.

Comment: Thank you @DalmTo. My argument is that DropBox are using "Open with Google Docs" which opens the Google docs editor. You are meaning that they are using a Google Drive Web app that uses Google Docs API to edit this document right?